# Windows Task Scheduler running application but cannot send email

Tags: windows, task, scheduled-tasks

In my windows task scheduler, I have scheduled a task to run a c# console application executable on a daily basis. This application sends some data to the database and then sends an email.

When I run it normally it works but however when it is run through task scheduler, it sends data to the database but is unable to send the email.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**EDIT: 


Yes I can send correctly through console application. It uses default network credentials..However when I look at the event logs I have the following .NET Runtime exception logged:


Framework Version: v4.0.30319

Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

Exception Info: System.IO.IOException

Stack:

   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPages.WritePageTree()

   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.Close()

   at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfDocument.Close()

   at iTextSharp.text.Document.Close()

   at ReadReutersRates.Program.SavePDF(System.DateTime)

   at ReadReutersRates.Program.Main(System.String[])




I think it has something to do with pdf file which I am attaching to the email. But it's quite strange that this works when I manually run it.**

Comment: What component do you use to send those emails? Your SMTP server is accessible from your winservice?

Comment: i use system.net.mail and yes my smtp server is accesible..

Comment: Any emails on badmail folder? Can you send correctly through a console application? How do you authenticate on smtp server?

Comment: Permissions issue? You should do a runtime check to see what user the application is running under. Run it normally and see what it outputs, then run it scheduled and see what it outputs.

Answer (score 0):

This is a permissions error, the user you're running the task as when running through the console will have more permissions than the user running the task.

It appears the PDF app you are using is trying to write to a temp file or similar and it doesn't have permissions. (I'm assuming the email has a PDF attachment or similar that is being generated on the fly)

If you made your task run as an administrator that should work, you could then run it as a more restricted user and work out which permissions to apply to where to lock it down.